# Heroku Amazon S3 fileserver how to do routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, amazon-s3

How to do routes with Amazon S3 fileserver?

I have uploaded my photographer folder to Amazon S3.

My public dictory I had the folder:

```
photographer
```

And in photographer I had the folders:

```
flv
images
quicktime
```

I have uploaded the photographer folder to Amazon S3.

How do I get Heroku to work with Amazon S3 and have the same routes as if the folder photographer was in the public directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume these files are static assets in which case you define an asset host as following in production.rb (and development.rb if you like):

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/"
```

Comment: I have added config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://mybucketname.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/" to production.rb but nothing is happend. I have visited the URL and it is given a 404 error

Comment: Found the problem. It should be: https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/mybucketname/

Comment: Strange I get access denied when visiting the URL with the browser. Still do not have solved the problem

Comment: I think it is because of the Amazon access key. Where should the key be written?

Comment: You probably just need to set read permissions on your uploaded files.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to grab the parameters (which subfolder and the filename) from the request and then redirect the request to the corresponding S3 address. There is some good information on this in the redirection section at [RailsGuides](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#redirection).